# Eliminating nested loops

Tags: python, algorithm, graph-theory

I have been given an assignment where I have to build a brute-force algorithm. Which has to find the optimal route through a graph containing 14400 vertices, 600 for each of the 24 hours in a day. At each of the 600 vertices it is possible to choose between 480 vertices for the next hour.

I have tried to build an algorithm, but the way it is now it isn't possible to traverse the graph, because I end up with a lot of nested loops. I am new to Python,
Is there any way to improve the algorithm?

```
Path = [0] * 2
S = [12, 9, 20];
K = 10
S[:] = [x - K for x in S]

for x in range(0,600):     #1.hour              
Path[0]= x
for y in range(-240,240):    # 2.hour
    hour2 = x+y
    if 0 <= hour2 <= 600:
         Path[1] = hour2             
         for y in range(-240,240):   # 3.hour
             hour3 = hour2 + y
             if 0 <= hour3 <= 600:
                 Path[2]= hour3
                 price = sum([a*b for a,b in zip(Path,S)])
                 if maxprice < price:
                     maxprice = price
                     Optimalpath = list(Path)
print Optimalpath
print maxprice
```

I have only shown the nested loops for the first 3 hours but if at all possible it has to iterate for all of the 24 hours.

Or am I thinking of this problem all wrong?

Comment: Recursion recursion recursion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At each of the 24 stages, there are at least 240 possibilities (and often as
many as 480). So there are at least `24**240` possible paths. That's more than
`10**57` paths. There is no way you can solve this problem by brute force. The
problem can be solved, however, using [linear programming
methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming).

---

As [BJ Myers suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35530802/eliminating-nested-loops/35531132#comment58751470_35530802), you could use recursion to generate all possible paths.
Suppose you had a [generator function](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators) that generated all possible paths of length 1. That's easy:

```
def generate_paths1():
    for i in range(600):
        yield [i]
```

You could use `generate_paths1` to generate all possible paths of length 2:

```
def generate_paths2():
    for path in generate_paths1():
        current = path[-1]
        low = max(current-240, 0)
        high = min(current+240, 600)
        for i in range(low, high):
            yield path+[i]
```

and you could use `generate_paths2` to generate all paths of length 3:

```
def generate_paths3():
    for path in generate_paths2():
        current = path[-1]
        low = max(current-240, 0)
        high = min(current+240, 600)
        for i in range(low, high):
            yield path+[i]
```

But wait! `generate_paths3` is practically the same function as
`generate_paths2`. Surely there is a better way. We can write one recursive
function that can do everything `generate_paths1`, `generate_paths2`, and
`generate_paths3` can -- and more:

```
def generate_paths(N):
    # moves = range(0, 601, 120)   # see below for why this is an improvement
    moves = range(601)
    if N == 1:
        for i in moves:
            yield [i]
    else:
        for path in generate_paths(N-1):
            current = path[-1]
            low = max(current-240, 0)
            high = min(current+240, 600)
            for i in [i for i in moves if low <= i <= high]:
                yield path+[i]

N = 3
for path in generate_paths(N):
    ...
```

---

While being able to generate all the paths is wonderful, the are just too many paths.
If we recognize the problem as a [linear programming (LP)
problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming), we can do better.

Your problem can be expressed as an LP problem like this:

```
Maximize price = sum([a*b for a, b in zip(S, path)])
Subject to:

    x[1] - x[0] <= 240
    x[0] - x[1] <= 240
    x[2] - x[1] <= 240
    x[1] - x[2] <= 240
    ...
```

One of the properties of the solution to a LP problem is that:

> if a feasible solution exists and if the (linear) objective function is
>     bounded, then the optimum value is always attained on the **boundary** of the optimal
>     level-set. (my emphasis)

therefore, you could replace `moves = range(601)` with

```
    moves = range(0, 601, 120)
    # [0, 120, 240, 360, 480, 600]
```

because the optimal solution will tend to use 600 to maximize the price when S is positive and use 0 to minimize the loss when S is negative. The other values in between are the maximum hops the optimal solution would need to move from 0 to 600 or from 600 down to 0.

This reduces the number of paths to `6**24` which is much much smaller than `240**24`, bust still too large to admit a brute-force solution.

---

Using [`scipy.optimimize.linprog`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.linprog.html) you could solve for optimal paths -- even for the full 24-stage problem -- like this:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.optimize as optimize

"""
Minimize: np.dot(S, x)
Subject to: np.dot(A, x) <= b
"""
N = 24
K = 10
S = np.random.randint(-K//2, +K//2, size=N)
A = np.zeros((2*(N-1), N), dtype=int)
for i in range(N-1):
    A[2*i, i:i+2] = (1, -1)
    A[2*i+1, i:i+2] = (-1, 1)
b = np.array([240]*A.shape[0])
bounds = [(0, 600)]*N
result = optimize.linprog(c=-S, A_ub=A, b_ub=b, bounds=bounds)

optimal_path = result.x
max_price = np.dot(S, optimal_path)
print('''S: {}
optimal_path: {}
price: {}'''.format(S, optimal_path, max_price))
```

which yields results like

```
S: [ 0  1  3  4 -5 -1  0 -3 -4  0  3  2 -5  1 -4 -1 -3  2  0 -2  0  4 -2  2]
optimal_path: [ 360.  600.  600.  360.  120.    0.    0.    0.    0.  240.  480.  240.
    0.  240.    0.    0.    0.  240.    0.  120.  360.  600.  360.  600.]
price: 8520.0
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. One question how did you calculate maximum hops the optimal solution would need?

Comment: I gained some intuition by finding the solution for very small `N` by brute
force. Later I realized this was a linear programming problem and therefore knew
optimal solutions always occur on the "boundary" (given the constraints). Here,
that means moving by the maximum amount -- 240.

Comment: That is to say, loosely, if you
are at 0 and wish to get to 600, but can only jump by at most 240, then you will
jump 240, then 480, then land at 600. Conversely, if you are at 600 and wish to
get to 0, you would jump (the maximum possible amount) to 360 (=600-240), then
120 to arrive at 0. So the only values used by optimal solutions are in `[0,
120, 240, 360, 480, 600]`.

Comment: Yet another question. In the brute-force method. I can see that the recursive function you have written works. But what I fail to understand is how it creates the path, since from my perspective N isn't changed.

Comment: You may want to go through the code by hand when `N=1` (easy) and `N=2` (harder, but not too hard). Notice when `N=2` that you reach `for path in generate_path(N-1)`. This is where `N` is changed. `generate_path(2)` calls `generate_path(1)`. And similarly, `generate_path(3)` calls `generate_path(2)`. And in general (for N>=2), `generate_path(N)` calls `generate_path(N-1)`.

Comment: Writing (and reading) recursive functions involves "wishful thinking". You "wish" for a magic blackbox -- the function `generate_paths` -- which returns all the paths of length `N`. You *assume* you have the function *before* you write it. You use the blackbox in the process of writing the definition. If you handle the base case `N=1` without recursive calls, then the rest "magically" works.

Comment: So when you see `for path in generate_path(N-1)` you can think, "This is going to generate all paths of length `N-1` (and I'm going to build all paths of length `N` by sticking `[i]` to the end of them)."

Answer (score 2):

You can use a combination of the following.

---

Consider making a loop body into a function.

```
for x in ...
    for y in ...
        for z in ...
            ...
```

The triple loop is daunting. However, consider this:

```
def process_xy(x, y):
    for z in ...

for x in ...
    for y in ...
        process_xy(x, y)
```

Not only did you reduce the code indentation, you've done the following:

1. You've created a smaller unit that can be debugged and tested independently (`process_xy`)
2. The remaining nested loops, while there, do something much simpler - just call a function.

---

Note that:

```
for x0 in a0:
    for x1 in a1:
        for x2 in a2:
             ....
```

is equivalent to

```
import itertools

for (x0, x1, x2) in itertools.product(a0, a1, a2):
    ...
```

This is mainly useful when the nested ranges don't depend on the outer ranges, though.